# how do I find and get text from a text file in python?

Tags: python

I have a text file with lines like this one:

`Cubo: 100% (left_x:  744   top_y:  395   width:  167   height:  181)`

I would like to assign the appropiate int for each one of the variables, something like: `left_x = 744, top_y = 395, width = 167, height = 181` but without having to do it manually.

Comment: You're going to have to _parse the data_ to "do it manually". Please share what you have thought about trying so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use a dictionary, not variables, but you can use regex to parse it. E.g.

```
import re

s = 'Cubo: 100% (left_x:  744   top_y:  395   width:  167   height:  181)'
fields = s[s.index('(')+1:-1]
data = {x[0]:int(x[1]) for x in re.findall(r'([a-z_]+):\s+(\d+)', fields)}
print(data['left_x']) #  744
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open a file by using the `open` method. For example, you could do

`external_code = open("src/external_path.txt")`
... and get the text inside of the file by doing...
`text = external_code.read()`

Because it returns the string, you will need to parse the data from it.
For the parsing, I am unsure what would the best route for it. You could split the string different keywords and set your variable based on what number resides with the keyword...

Also, you may want to include more information next time you post; people tend to get a little annoyed with it. :/

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of information, this is my first question. I will try to include more information next time.

Comment: This answers how to open a file, sure. Not how to parse the data